# ring buffer for audio in python

Tags: python, audio, buffer

I am looking for a way to have a ring buffer in Python for audio. I want to be able to be rotating the storage in memory so that I don't waste RAM or HDD space and then when the user presses a button save that buffer to the disk.

Why? Because I want to implement something where the user presses a button and it saves the past 10 seconds (before the user pressed the button) plus an additional 10 seconds (after the user pressed the button) to the HDD.

Any pointers or tips?